# How to have two database connections in a single config file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a class that looks like this:

```
package com.mycom.mycust.mysql.dbconnection;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("mysql")
public class ConnectionProperties {

    private String db1Url;
    private String db2Url;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getDb1Url() {
        return db1Url;
    }

    public void setDb1Url(String url) {
        db1Url = url;
    }

    public String getDb2Url() {
        return db2Url;
    }

    public void setDb2Url(String url) {
        db2Url = url;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

It gets its config from a file located at mycust/config/application.properties:

```
mysql.db1Url=jdbc:mysql://index.prod.cr:1234/db1
mysql.db2Url=jdbc:mysql://index.prod.cr:1234/db2
mysql.username=mycom
mysql.password=mypass
```

As you can see, this file contains two different URL:s. Furthermore, there is a file mycust/mysql-parent/object-mapper/src/main/resources/application.properties which seems to serve the function of giving names to each part of the previously shown config file:

```
# Connection settings for prod MySQL database
mysql.db1Url=jdbc:mysql://host:port/database
mysql.db2Url=jdbc:mysql://host:port/database
mysql.username=username
mysql.password=password
```

When I run the jar of my application, I see that the string `"port"` from the file above has been used as the port number, which is obviously wrong. If I put all the credentials of mycust/config/application.properties inside mycust/mysql-parent/object-mapper/src/main/resources/application.properties, the correct credentials are found, but I don't think this is how the program is meant to run. Previously, when I was only connecting to one database, mycust/mysql-parent/object-mapper/src/main/resources/application.properties contained only placeholder names of all the credentials which mycust/config/application.properties had the actual credentials. Why does this setup not work now that I have two databases that I'm connecting to?

Comment: which orm,mybatis or hibernate?

Comment: I have my own ORM.